# How can I remove spaces and \n\l values at the fastest way?

Tags: php

I wrote a caching class. It automatically gets the page content after many database queries and saves it as a .html file. Every 600 seconds, it reads from this .html page instead of querying.

To improve reading speed even faster, I want to remove unwanted characters like " " (space) \n\l and such. How can I do this?

I know I can do this in many ways. trim, str_replace and so on. I want to know the fastest - and the safest (so it won't break javascript) way to rely on. :)

Thank you.

Comment: When producing this cache-file, why not echo the whole .html file without \n? Then you don't need to do this. Any why do you ask about javascript? Does this html-file include more than queries?

Comment: I suggest that you measure this. I think, you're saving pennies here. Not worth the effort.

Comment: @OptimusCrime If I echo the whole .html file without \'s, then a kind of replace \n's function will be called every time the page gets requested. That's why I want to save it as much as I can minify.

Answer (score 2):

My advice to you: **don't**.

Unless your templates are made so poorly that they generate markup that consists mostly of spaces.

You want a way to remove spaces that is simple, fast and safe. But in reality you can choose only two of these three properties.

- If you want simple and fast: use str_replace, but it breaks your javascript.
- If you want simple and safe: edit files yourself and remove spaces manually.
- If you want fast and safe: you'll have to use some complex parsers and/or optimization tools.

It's up to you!

Comment: Currently, the page I am caching contains 700 lines of HTML code, and pretty much spaces in every line. Also inline javascript. Current page load time is 0,020 seconds. I want it to be faster, but if it doesn't worth it, I better keep it like this.

Comment: Don't guess, measure it! With numbers at hand you can make an educated decision.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose using `str_replace` is the fastest way! An alternative would be `preg_replace`, but regular expressions are not as fast as simple string replacements.

Some time ago I have written this method, to tidy up some sourcecode:

```
private function makeTiny($source, $type) {
    // Get replacements
    $replacements = array();

    if ($this->conf[$type]['stripTabs']) {
        $replacements[] = "\t";
    }
    if ($this->conf[$type]['stripNewLines']) {
        $replacements[] = "\n";
        $replacements[] = "\r";
    }

    // Do replacements
    $source = str_replace($replacements, '', $source);

    // Strip comments
    if ($this->conf[$type]['stripComments']) {
        $source = preg_replace('/<\!\-\-.*?\-\->/is', '', $source);
    }

    // Strip double spaces
    if ($this->conf[$type]['stripDoubleSpaces']) {
        $source = preg_replace('/( {2,})/is', ' ', $source);
    }
    if ($this->conf[$type]['stripTwoLinesToOne']) {
        $source = preg_replace('/(\n{2,})/is', "\n", $source);
    }
    return $source;
}
```

As far as I remember, this is not killing inline javascript! But you should try it before.

Comment: What about javascript string literals? :-)

Comment: but did you test it on a real page? :-)

Comment: Yes! But I'm such a faithful developer, that I never use inline javascript ;-) It is part of a TYPO3 Extension called "tinysource".

Comment: You can see the extension running here: http://goo.gl/e5gZR But no inline javascript existing!

Answer (score 1):

Keep attention to your javascript code first, if you have javascript comments it can break your javascript code.

Have a look into [Yui compressor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/) and/or [Google Closure Compressor](http://code.google.com/intl/fr-CA/closure/compiler/) to optimize your javascript first.

For the rest of the page, you can pass it in thoses handy functions

[Compressing your HTML, CSS and Javascript using simple PHP Code](http://gadelkareem.com/2007/06/23/compressing-your-html-css-and-javascript-using-simple-php-code/)

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$newcontent = preg_replace('/(\n|\s|\t)+/','',$oldcontent);
```

this will replace the space and tab and new line

Comment: What about javascript string literals? :-)